# Not sending file correctly. Sockets. C

Tags: c, sockets, recv, sendfile

I am writing a program that a client can ask for files to a server. Then the server will send them in chunks of 512 bytes. The problem is that when the client read the file:

*Sometimes the first 512 bytes are different from the original file. The total read file also has a different size (and obviously it also ends different from the original file) and therefore the client loop that writes to the new file does never end.

*Sometimes it works perfectly and i don't know why.

**Server:**

```
            /* Check if file exists */
            if(access(retrFileName, F_OK) == 0){

                /* Open file */
                fd = open(retrFileName, O_RDONLY); 
                lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
                if (fd == -1){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file --> %s", strerror(errno));

                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                /* Get file stats */
                if (fstat(fd, &fileStat) < 0){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error fstat --> %s", strerror(errno));
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                sprintf(fileSize, "%li", fileStat.st_size);

                /* Sending file data */
                offset = 0;
                remainData = fileStat.st_size;
                while (((sentBytes = sendfile(clientSock, fd, &offset, 512)) == 512) && (remainData > 0)) {
                        remainData -= sentBytes;
                        fprintf(stdout, "Server envio %d bytes del file, offset ahora vale: %li y quedan = %d bytes\n", sentBytes, offset, remainData);
                }
                remainData -= sentBytes;
                fprintf(stdout, "Server envio %d bytes del file, offset ahora vale: %li y quedan = %d bytes\n", sentBytes, offset, remainData);//do while
                close(fd);////////////////////////
                send(clientSock, NICETRANSFER, sizeof(NICETRANSFER), 0); //LO METE AL ARCHIVO
                printf("send\n");
                //close(clientSock);///////////

            }
            else{
                send(clientSock, FILEERROR, sizeof(FILEERROR), 0);
                printf("send\n");
            }


        }
```

**Client:**

```
/* Open file */
            receivedFile = fopen("r.txt", "wb");
            if (receivedFile == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file --> %s\n", strerror(errno));

                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            /* Write to the file */
            int contador = 0;
            int remainData = fileSize;
            do{
                if(remainData < 512)
                    bytesLeidos = recv(clientSock, readingBuffer, remainData, 0);
                else
                    bytesLeidos = recv(clientSock, readingBuffer, 512, 0);

                fwrite(readingBuffer, bytesLeidos, 1, receivedFile);

                remainData -= 512;
                contador += 512;
                printf("bytesleidos: %li, contador: %d:\n%s\n\n", bytesLeidos, contador, readingBuffer);

            }while(contador < fileSize);
            fclose(receivedFile);
```

Comment: `/* Check if file exists */
            if(access(retrFileName, F_OK)` is completely useless.  Even if the `access()` call succeeds, the later `open()` call can fail.  Doing X to try to make sure Y will work later is almost always a bad idea - for one, it's [a TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  Just call `open()` and handle any failure - you have to do that anyway.

Comment: Why are you looping while `sendfile()` returns 512? It can return *any* positive number <= the stated buffer size.

Comment: we will have a difficult time recreating your bug, because all that is posted is code snippets.  Please post a [mcve] for the client and for the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem!! I needed to sync both client and server. To do so, the server send the size of the file and waits for an answer for the client with `recv`. When the client recieve the file size, it `send` a "" message.

I don't know if this is the correct solution, but this way you can sync server and client.

After sync, the server send the respective file normally with `sendfile`

Answer (score 4):

Golden rule of socket programming: Always check the return value from `recv`. It's not always what you think it will be.

Even though you "send" 512 bytes at a time, you are in no way guaranteed that TCP will deliver the same number of bytes at a time to the receiver.  TCP segmentation, IP fragmentation, and general Internet weirdness will cause the recv side to get an arbitrary number of bytes at a time.

Hence, your hardcoded assumption that `recv` will always return 512 is incorrect:

```
remainData -= 512;
contador += 512;
```

Instead, you should be saying:

```
remainData -= bytesLeidos;
contador += bytesLeidos;
```

An you need to check for errors and socket closing too.

This is an improved main loop for your client code:

```
while (remainData > 0)
{
    size_t recvSize = (remainData >= 512) ? 512 : remainData;
    bytesLeidos = recv(clientSock, readingBuffer, recvSize, 0);
    if (bytesLeidos > 0)
    {
        fwrite(readingBuffer, bytesLeidos, 1, receivedFile);
        remainData -= bytesLeidos;
        contador += bytesLeidos;

        /* null terminate readingBuffer so garbage isn't printed.*/
        /* Make sure readingBuffer is allocated to be at least */
        /*  N+1 bytes (513) to account for this character being appended. */

        readingBuffer[bytesLeidos] = '\0'; 
        printf("bytesleidos: %li, contador: %d:\n%s\n\n", bytesLeidos, contador, readingBuffer);
    }
    else if (bytesLeidos == 0)
    {
        /* remote side closed connection */
        printf("Remote side exited connection\n");
        break;   
    }
    else if (bytesLeidos < 0)
    {
         /* connection error */
        printf("Connection error\n");
        break;   
    }
}
```

Comment: i am having the same problem with your solution. When i go `printf("bytesleidos: %li, contador: %d:\n%s\n\n", bytesLeidos, contador, readingBuffer);` for the first time, it prints something different from the beginning of the original file. Also, the loop don't end; the client output ends with

__bytesleidos: 103, contador: 2151:__ (and my original file size is 3062)

Also, the server (or the client idk) write into the new file the message sent after sending(recieving) the file

Comment: My psychic powers suggest that are you forgetting to null terminate `readingBuffer` with a zero.  Literally add this line `readBuffer[bytesLeidos] = '\0';` before the `printf` statement.

Comment: No. Change the `printf()` to `printf("bytesleidos: %li, contador: %d:\n%.*s\n\n", bytesLeidos, contador, bytesLeidos, readingBuffer)`. You should not mess with the read buffer.

Comment: The printf statement change is a good idea. But null terminating the read buffer also makes debugging easier - especially for text protocols. We're already programming in "C", so the safety belts are already off...

Comment: Still having the problem. When i boot my computer the program works perfectly. The problem is after the first try, the client (i guess) don't recieve the full file correctly

Comment: What have you done to debug to understand the issue? Do you think the issue is on server or client?