# recv function doesn't receive all the data sent

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing a server-client program for an university exam, I won't write every detail of the assignment for obvious reasons, but it seems that I'm stuck on the last part of the project, which is, in my honest opinion, very odd (it will be clear why in a second).

To summarize what I'm trying to achieve, the code should work like this (after setting up the server - client connection with -as requested by the assignment- the TCP/IP protocol):

1. client will send files to server (with a command)
2. server will compress those files (with another command)
3. server will send back the compressed file

The first two points of this -basic- scheme are already implemented and work pretty well, but somehow sending back the data is somewhat impossibile and I have no error to work with; I wrote two functions (identical between the server.c and client.c file) which are the *send_file(int socket, ssize_t size_to_send, FILE* file_to_send)* and *recv_file(int socket, ssize_t size_to_recv, FILE* file_to_recv)* in the following way:

**Recv_file**

```
void recv_file(int socket, ssize_t size_recv, FILE* fp){
    char buffer[BUFLEN] = {'\0'};
    ssize_t rcv = 1;
    long rcv_inc = 0;
    int eof = 0;
    while( rcv_inc <= size_recv  ){
        if( (rcv = recv(socket, buffer, BUFLEN, 0)) < 0 ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Errore nella ricezione del file:%s\n",strerror(errno));
            close(socket);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
                fputs(buffer, fp);
        rcv_inc += strlen(buffer);
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("\rserver> Progresso: %lu / %lu", rcv_inc, size_recv);
        
    }
    fseek(fp, (size_recv - rcv_inc), SEEK_END);
    fputc('\0', fp);
    
}
```

**Send_file**

```
void send_file(int socket, ssize_t size_to_send, FILE* fp){
    long bufinc = 0;
    ssize_t snd = 1;
    char buffer[BUFLEN] = {'\0'};
    while( !feof(fp) ){
        fgets(buffer, BUFLEN, fp);
        if( (snd = send(socket, buffer, BUFLEN, 0)) < 0 ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'invio del file: %s, inviati %lu B su %lu B totali.\n", strerror(errno), snd, size_to_send);
            close(socket);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        bufinc += strlen(buffer);
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("\rserver> Progresso: %lu / %lu (%lu)", bufinc, size_to_send, snd);
    }
    
}
```

Maybe for inexperience, or maybe because I didn't understood how the recv and send work, it seems that the recv_file doesn't meet the condition to end the *while* 100% of the times when I'm waiting for the compressed file (so from *server* to *client*), and sometimes (so about 5% of the times) when I'm waiting for the files (so from *client* to *server*).

Since I have no errors to work with, I'd say that this is somewhat related to possible race-conditions I'm not aware of or any kind of kernel tomfoolery that I don't get.
I hope that anyone can help me figuring this out.

Comment: Can the compressed content contain a null terminator?  If so, `strlen` is the wrong choice and you need to track what you've received using `recv`'s return value.

Comment: I've answered this question A LOT.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027020/104458

Comment: `fputs` is meant for strings.

Comment: A few things: neither `recv()` or `send()` or `fgets()` will always read/write the requested number of bytes; you're assuming `fgets()` and `send()` do. You're treating the bytes read by `recv()` as a normal 0 terminated C string which you can't depend on. And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong

Comment: The easy fix is to use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag to receive all `BUFLEN` bytes on the recv call instead of getting a partial message.

Comment: I'll close on this. Design your recv code such that it can handle receiving a single byte a time.  That is, it shouldn't matter if you receive all BUFLEN bytes in a single receive, half the bytes, or just 1 byte... if you implement your code correctly such that you invoke recv until you get all the data needed..... then you will have a robust implementation.

Comment: I read all of your comments and I thank you all, as you have pointed out strlen might be the major issue here (I have to test it and I'll come back). @selbie about the flag, I've already tried it -I wrote my own question after a couple days of tries and extensive research here on stack- but it didn't seem to do anything at all (but maybe it wasn't doing anything due to my use of strlen).

Answer (score 2):

The following line is incorrect for a couple of reasons:

```c
rcv_inc += strlen(buffer);
```

- It assumes the bytes returned will be terminated by a NUL.
- It assumes there is no NUL in the data.

The first assumption is most definitely incorrect. Even if you send a NUL at the end of every message, there's no guarantee that `recv` will return exactly one message.

Since we're talking about compression, the second assumption is probably also incorrect. Compressed files can typically contains NUL bytes.

Fix:

```c
rcv_inc += rcv;
```

---

Other issues:

- `rcv_inc <= size_recv` should be `rcv_inc < size_recv`.
- You shouldn't read `BUFLEN`; you should read at most `size_recv - rcv_inc`.
- `while( !feof(fp) )` is wrong. You can't use `feof` to check if a handle will return EOF. `feof` check if the previous read returned EOF.
- `send` may send less than the requested amount. You need to call it in a loop like you do for `recv`.
- You don't check if `recv` returned 0 (which indicates EOF). If that happens, you end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `rcv_inc += rcv`, if that is the case, then I'll change right away, thanks for the advice about the NUL byte, I didn't think of it.

Comment: woops, yeah. Fixed.

Comment: Shouldn't `while( rcv_inc <= size_recv  )` be `while( rcv_inc < size_recv  )`?

Comment: That too. Added.

Comment: Sorry for my slow reply (I'm finding this comment textbox a bit weird to use, still a newbie in stackexchange); anyway, I don't get why the `while( rcv_inc <= size_recv)` be worse than the version with the strict disequality, since with the "<=" version" should include also the cycle with the EOF char, while the other one won't (I don't know if this is correct theory-wise, but my tests show that is better to use the "<=" more than "<"), said that I have a way to handle the EOF. Finally, I tried the new suggestion, modify them a bit and now it "works" more or less.

Comment: What if it's not EOF? The checks would get quite complicated. If you want to make  sure EOF follows, that's best handled after the loop.